# Getting closest next or previous div while active or inactive

Tags: jquery, tabs

I know my title sounds confusing, but bear with me...

I am working on a web browser with tabs. While in an active tab, I want it to stay active when I close inactive tabs to the left and right of it. For the time being, my code only works when I have two tabs open and if it is the second one being active. If the first tab is active and I want to close the second tab, the second does indeed close, but the first tab loses focus.

```
if (tabCount > 1) {

    if ($(this).parent(".tab").hasClass("active")) {

        if (tab.next(".tab").length != null) { // if next tab exists
            tab.nextAll().first().addClass("active");
        } else { // select previous tab
            tab.prevAll().first().addClass("active");
        }

        $(this).parent(".tab").remove();

    } else {

        $(this).parent(".tab").remove();

    }

}
```

If seeing the entire project would help anyone help me, it is here: https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Aries.

Comment: better to create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @AmitKumar It's actually better to just run the app, there isn't any setup involved. It's too much for a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the `detach` method

[Jquery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

```
if (tabCount > 1) {
    //Caching for performance
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parent(".tab").hasClass("active")) {
        //place all active tabs in a variable
        var activetabs = $this.parents(".tab.active").detach();
        //Empty tab parent div, and put the active tabs back in
         $this.parents(".tab").parent().empty().append(activetabs);            

    } else {

        $this.parent(".tab").remove();
    }

}
```